# Starting out with a REST server and a Coffeescript frontend

Tags: javascript, python, json, rest, flask

Looking for some help on where to begin, there are so many competing libraries and acronyms I get all dizzy trying to sort it all out.

I would like to

- Create a REST backend (probably Python with Flask, in this case)
- A frontend served up entirely with static HTML and static Javascript (or Coffeescript)

I am more at home with the backend stuff, need more advice on the frontend stuff. <sub>I realize this question is not a super good fit for the SO question format, please help me improve it, 'cause I could really use some guidance here.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this demo, [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) should help you decide between different methods. ([TodoMVC on Github](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc).)

I prefer to use jQuery for working with REST backends, but you can choose any other framework.